# How do I get a script to cause an edit-based trigger?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets script that automatically edits a cell in my sheet with a timed trigger, and I would like a second part of the script to run once that edit is automatically made. However, the Google Script Guides say this:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling FormResponse.submit() to submit a new form response
>   does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.

Is there anyway around this? What solutions are available to me?

Answer (score 2):

Include a call to your onEdit function from the functions that make changes to your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If your time based trigger changes cell `A1` for example, you can invoke "edit" trigger by calling [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) function with defined `e.range` parameter:

```
// get cell
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1');

// change cell value
cell.setValue('changed!');

// call onEdit directly
onEdit({range: cell});
```